# What is the correct way to read a series of characters using getchar?

Tags: c, getchar

I have two examples of source code. I have always used the first example, but strangely the character '0' I find it at the beginning of the array (which with the second example does not happen). Why does the first example put the character '0' at the beginning of the array?

example1:

```
/*
    Enter a sentence: ciao
    0 -> \0
    1 -> c
    2 -> i
    3 -> a
    4 -> o
    5 -> \0
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 6

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    char ch, last_char, sentence[MAX] = { };

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && i++ < MAX) {
        sentence[i] = ch;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if(sentence[i] == '\0')
            printf("%d -> \\0\n", i);
        else
            printf("%d -> %c\n", i, sentence[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example2:

```
/*
    Enter a sentence: ciao
    0 -> c
    1 -> i
    2 -> a
    3 -> o
    4 -> \0
    5 -> \0
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 6

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    char ch, last_char, sentence[MAX] = { };

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        sentence[i] = ch;
        if(i++ >= MAX - 1) break;   
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if(sentence[i] == '\0')
            printf("%d -> \\0\n", i);
        else
            printf("%d -> %c\n", i, sentence[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use do while, `do{
  ch = getchar(); 
        sentence[i] = ch;
    }while (ch != '\n' && i++ < MAX);`

Comment: The first is just incorrect, I doubt that you have _"always used"_ it if you have ever written code that works.  The second is not particularly elegant, but if those are the choices you are limiting the question to, the second is the only semantically correct one.   Better to make the question less restrictive and simply ask how to read a sequence of characters using `getchar()` - there are many correct ones, but you'll get a number of answers and comments on them and can choose the most appropriate. One with an EOF check would be more "correct" that either of these.

Comment: @EsmaeelE : that way the `'\n'` ends up in the array.  Besides if you have an answer, post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing `i++` in the `while` condition. So it's incrementing `i` *before* you use it as the index in the assignment. You can test the index without incrementing it, and do the auto-increment in the assignment.

```
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && i < MAX) {
        sentence[i++] = ch;
    }
```

You should actually change the order of the `&&` operands. There's no point in reading a character if you've reached the end of the array and won't be able to assign it.

```
    while (i < MAX && (ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        sentence[i++] = ch;
    }
```

Comment: would it be possible to have the increment of i in the while statement if ++i is used instead of i++?

Comment: No, that still won't work. Either way, the variable will be incremented before the assignment.

Comment: @BramAppel : If you insist, you simply need to initialise `i` to -1 instead of zero.

Comment: Exactly what I thought too. I put I++ because I imagined that i was incremented after the first pass ...

Comment: @Clifford, well I don't but appreciate your suggestion. However, I would consider it a hack and it won't improve readability either.

Comment: @RobertoRocco No, the `while()` condition is executed *before* the body. If you want it executed after, you need to use `do {...} while(condition);`

Comment: @BramAppel : No it won't improve readability.  Use a `for` is you want the increment in the loop statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && i++ < MAX) {
    sentence[i] = ch;
}
```

Start from `i=0`. We see if the read-in character is not a newline, and if so, we see if `i` is less than `MAX`. Afterward, `i` is incremented (now it's 1). If the comparison was true, we set `sentence[i]` (which is the same as `sentence[1]`) to `ch`. So the first position, `sentence[0]`, is never assigned to. This is the bug.

In the second example, you have a for loop, which is correct because the incrementing of `i` takes place last.

Comment: `EOF` is not equal to '\n' so you're going to fill the array with `EOF` on error.

Answer (score 1):

There are many "correct" solutions; the "best" is a matter of opinion, but your first solution is semantically incorrect, and the second unnecessarily inelegant.

The first could be "corrected" by initialising `i` to -1, but that would not be idiomatic.  Also neither of your suggestions check for EOF which can occur when for example redirecting input from a file, or with a platform specific CTRL key combination.

The following localises the index variable and checks for EOF:

```
for( int i = 0;
     i < MAX &&                   // Will fit in buffer AND 
     (ch = getchar()) != '\n' &&  // is not newline AND
     ch != EOF;                   // is not end-of-file
     i++ ;
{
    sentence[i] = ch ;
}
```

This makes sense since it exactly mirrors your *output* loop.  The localisation if `i` prevents maintenance issues that might occur from the use of `i` for different purposes within this code.  You should similarly localise the output index.

Neither of your implementations reserves space for a nul terminator, which may be deliberate, but otherwise, either:

```
char sentence[MAX + 1] ;
```

of the limiting sub-expression `i < MAX - 1`, or better `i < sizeof(sentence) - 1` - the latter guarding against changes to the declaration of `sentence` perhaps using something other than `MAX` under future maintenance or reuse.